# Remove space in row caused by \cmidrule in table

Tags: tables, spacing, bookmarks

I would like to

- either remove the extra space around "entry with space" in the table below
- or to extend the spacing between the entries overall.

My goal is that the spacing throughout the table looks nice and clean, despite the use of `\cmidrule`.
Anyone an idea how to achieve that? Thanks in advance!

[image: table with extra vertical space]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}

%for figures and tables, captions
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[th]
    \caption[table title]{table title}
    \centering\scriptsize
    \begin{tabular*}
        {\columnwidth}{
        @{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
        cc
        @{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
        }
        \toprule
        %
        {Column 1} & 
        {Column 2.1} \\
        \cmidrule{1-1} \cmidrule{2-2}
        %
        entry & entry\\
        entry & entry\\
        entry & entry\\
        entry & \\
        \cmidrule{2-2}
        entry with space & {Column 2.2}\\
        \cmidrule{2-2}
        entry & entry\\
        entry & entry\\
        entry & entry\\
        %
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe using `\cline{}` instead?

Comment: It seems like Column 1 doesn't really have anything to do with Column 2.  Is that correct?  Does Column 2.1 have anything to do with Column 2.2?

Comment: That's correct, Column 2.2 does not have anything to do with Column 2.1. That both are in the same column is because I tried to condense the table due to space restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comment by Sigur, `\cline` protrudes in the row below. That's for historical reasons (remark in particular that `\hline` does not protrude) and it's a complication in some constructions).

```
\documentclass{article}

%for figures and tables, captions
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[th]
    \caption[table title]{table title}
    \centering\scriptsize
    \begin{tabular*}
        {\columnwidth}{
        @{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
        cc
        @{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
        }
        \toprule
        %
        {Column 1} & 
        {Column 2.1} \\
        \cmidrule{1-1} \cmidrule{2-2}
        %
        entry & entry\\
        entry & entry\\
        entry & entry\\
        entry & \\
        \cline{2-2}
        entry with space & {Column 2.2}\\
        \cline{2-2}
        entry & entry\\
        entry & entry\\
        entry & entry\\
        %
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

You can also solve your problem with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. Remark that, in `{NiceTabular}`, `\cline` does *not* protrude by design (but there is a key `standard-cline` to go back to the standard behavior).

In fact, I speak of `{NiceTabular}` because, in that environment you have PGF/Tikz nodes created under the rows, cells and columns of the array, and you can use those nodes with Tikz to draw whatever rule you want after the construction of the array (hence without modifying the geometry of the array...)

However, for technical reasons, you have to switch to a syntax in the style of `tabularx` is your case.

```
\documentclass{article}

%for figures and tables, captions
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[th]
    \caption[table title]{table title}
    \centering\scriptsize
    \begin{NiceTabularX}
        {\columnwidth}{cXc}
        \toprule
        %
        {Column 1} && 
        {Column 2.1} \\
        \cmidrule{1-1} \cmidrule{3-3}
        %
        entry && entry\\
        entry && entry\\
        entry && entry\\
        entry && \\
        entry with space && {Column 2.2}\\
        entry && entry\\
        entry && entry\\
        entry && entry\\
        %
        \bottomrule
    \CodeAfter
        \begin{tikzpicture}
           \draw ([yshift=0.6ex]6-|3) -- ([yshift=0.6ex]6-|4) ; 
           \draw (7-|3) -- (7-|4) ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{NiceTabularX}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The main interest is that you can adjust the position of your rules (with `yshift=0.6ex` in my example).

[image: Output of the above code]

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the fast response and help!